# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: Eclipse Mac OSX

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, osx-mavericks, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to build my project in the eclipse luna cdt environment. It appears that the linker is having an issue with my code. I'm completely inexperienced with linkers and compilers and have no idea how to approach the problem. I tried compiling the code outside the IDE and have a similar problem. Here is the message that Eclipse gives me when I try to build the project. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
17:09:25 **** Build of configuration Debug for project Assignment 1 ****
make all 
Building file: ../linkedList.C
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"linkedList.d" -MT"linkedList.d" -o "linkedList.o" "../linkedList.C"
Finished building: ../linkedList.C

Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
Finished building: ../main.cpp

Building target: Assignment 1
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
g++  -o "Assignment 1"  ./linkedList.o ./main.o   
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "LinkedList<int>::print(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      vtable for LinkedList<int> in main.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& operator<<<int>(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, LinkedList<int>&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Assignment 1] Error 1

17:09:27 Build Finished (took 1s.729ms)
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing the standard libraries.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you perhaps point me in the general direction as to how I would go about installing them? Is it a matter of installing them in eclipse or the OS?

Comment: They should be there.  Something is not set up right.  Eclipse should know where they are and does not.  Are you on Unix/Linux?  If so, you need to have the static and dynamic library paths set up correctly.

Comment: I'm on OSX Yosemite. I've installed Xcode and I seem to be getting a similar issue with preprocessing. I'll update if I find anything out